# Track onBlur event on Parent Div only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prepare a custom dropdown control for my application. The requirement goes here.

Main Flow:
If i click on the textbox, a div opens and user need to select a item from the div. the selected item needs to be filled into the textbox.

Alternate Flow : If the user clicks on the textbox and later clicks on somewhere on the screen except the dropdown div, the dropdown div should close.

I am able to achieve the main flow easily. I am unable to script code for the alternate flow i have mentioned. I have tried the simple blur event, it didnt work.

Please help me solve the issue.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="display-none food-textbox" id="txtFood"  value="None"/>
<div class="food-dropdown display-none"> 
    <div class="food-item">Curled Spinach</div>
    <div class="food-item">Veg Mayo</div>
    <div class="food-item">French Toast</div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnFoodTargetTxt"/>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('.food-textbox').on('click', function () {
    var positionOfTb = $(this).offset();
    var widthofTb = $(this).width();
    $('.food-dropdown').removeClass('display-none').offset({ top: positionOfTb.top, left: positionOfTb.left }).css('width', widthofTb + 10);
    $('.food-dropdown').focus();
    $('#hdnFoodTargetTxt').val($(this).attr('id'));
});

$('.food-item').on('click', function () {
    var targetTxt = '#' + $('#hdnFoodTargetTxt').val();
    $(targetTxt).val($(this).html());
    $(targetTxt).next().eq(0).val($(this).html());
    $('.food-dropdown').addClass('display-none');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop the click propagation using [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) and add a click handler on the document to close the opened dropdown.

Code:

```
$('.food-textbox').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var positionOfTb = $(this).offset();
    var widthofTb = $(this).width();
    $('.food-dropdown').removeClass('display-none').offset({ top: positionOfTb.top, left: positionOfTb.left }).css('width', widthofTb + 10);
    $('.food-dropdown').focus();
    $('#hdnFoodTargetTxt').val($(this).attr('id'));
});

$('.food-item').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var targetTxt = '#' + $('#hdnFoodTargetTxt').val();
    $(targetTxt).val($(this).html());
    $(targetTxt).next().eq(0).val($(this).html());
    $('.food-dropdown').addClass('display-none');
});

$(document).on('click', function () {
    $('.food-dropdown').addClass('display-none');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/PKndL/

Comment: The appears to work, but breaks as soon as something loses focus through any other means (such as hitting tab)